# C++ expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type

Tags: c++

I overloaded parenthesis and I called but I got error.
Code is as written hereunder.

```
//Matrix43.h
class Matrix43 {
public:
    Matrix43();
    void operator()(
        double, double, double,
        double, double, double,
        double, double, double, 
        double, double, double);
private:
    double m00, m01, m02;
    double m10, m11, m12;
    double m20, m21, m22;
    double m30, m31, m32;
};
```

```
//Matrix43.cpp
#include "Matrix43.h"

Matrix43::Matrix43() :
    m00(0.0), m01(0.0), m02(0.0),
    m10(0.0), m11(0.0), m12(0.0),
    m20(0.0), m21(0.0), m22(0.0),
    m30(0.0), m31(0.0), m32(0.0) {
}
void Matrix43::operator()(
    double e00, double e01, double e02,
    double e10, double e11, double e12, 
    double e20, double e21, double e22, 
    double e30, double e31, double e32) {
    m00 = e00; m01 = e01; m02 = e02;
    m10 = e10; m11 = e11; m12 = e12;
    m20 = e20; m21 = e21; m22 = e22;
    m30 = e30; m31 = e31; m32 = e32;
}
```

I call operator like this and got error.

```
//main.cpp
#include "Matrix43.h"

Matrix43* a;

    int main() {
        a = new Matrix43;
//C++ expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type
        *a(
            -150.0, -100.0, -300.0,
            150.0, -100.0, -300.0,
            -150.0, -100.0, 300.0,
            150.0, -100.0, 300.0
        );
        delete a;
                return 0;
    }
```

I found using local variable which has reference type can solve this error.

```
#main.cpp
#include "Math/Matrix43.h"

Matrix43* a;

    int main() {
        a = new Matrix43;
        Matrix43& o = *a;
        o(
            -150.0, -100.0, -300.0,
            150.0, -100.0, -300.0,
            -150.0, -100.0, 300.0,
            150.0, -100.0, 300.0
        );
        delete a;
                return 0
    }
```

But I would like to call operator through using *a so as to know exactly a is calling that.
Is there any solutions?

those codes are parts of a project, some points may looks strange.
If you have noticed, please tell me and I will add code propery.
(In the project that main function loops and I need to initialize value without constructor.)

Kind regards

Comment: `a->operator()(/*the arguments*/);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
*a(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

It is parsed as:

```
*(a(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));
```

Which is not what you wanted. So you're going to need to be more explicit with parentheses and do:

```
(*a)(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

Comment: You may also want to show the not-too-often-used `operator()` syntax that I made in the main comments.

Comment: Thank you both of you guys. 
I’ll try when I home.

Comment: Thank you.
Both suggestions have worked perfectly as I wanted.
Two of you saved my day.